# R line graph with Points highlighted in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am trying to recreate the chart below in ggplot, I was wondering if someone could help me out. The highlighted red point are where it is considered a spike.

[image]

[image]

Month   # of Sales  Roll12  Roll26  Type
1   106 70.6    72.5    Spike
2   92  73.9    73.9    Condition
3   97  77.1    74.7    Spike
4   75  77.5    75.8    Normal
5   74  77.6    76.3    Normal
6   78  78.4    75.8    Normal
7   76  79.3    75.7    Normal
8   100 80.8    75.2    Spike
9   68  79.9    75.1    Decrease
10  73  79.3    74.9    Decrease
11  64  78.6    75.1    Decrease
12  60  77.5    74.2    Decrease

Thank you,

MS

Comment: please inlcude your data using e.g. `?dput()` rather then posting a picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
df <- structure(list(Month = 1:12, Sales = c(106L, 92L, 97L, 
75L, 74L, 78L, 76L, 100L, 68L, 73L, 64L, 60L), Roll12 = c(70.6, 
73.9, 77.1, 77.5, 77.6, 78.4, 79.3, 80.8, 79.9, 79.3, 78.6, 77.5),
Roll26 = c(72.5, 73.9, 74.7, 75.8, 76.3, 75.8, 75.7, 75.2, 
75.1, 74.9, 75.1, 74.2), Type = structure(c(4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Condition", "Decrease", 
"Normal", "Spike"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), .Names = c("Month", "Sales", "Roll12", "Roll26", 
"Type"))

# need to convert the dataframe to long format for plotting; 
# you should change the `variable.name="variable"` and `value.name="value"` args here to whatever you want to call them
df <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("Month", "Type"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Month, y = value, color = variable)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(data = df[df[["Type"]] == "Spike" & df[["variable"]] == "Sales", ], color="red")
```

[image: soplot2]

Comment: Thank you! That reshape2 package is fantastic